# Mock Http backend for use in Mockups

Tags: angular, http

is there a way to mock the Http object of Angular 2, the dream would be to use this for the mockups and have mockups that are identical to the core code except for the connection sent to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `MockBackend`, ensure this is registered in DI after the default `Backend` so this gets used instead
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/testing/MockBackend-class.html

```ts
import {DefaultOptions, Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {MockBackend} from 'angular2/http/testing';
it('should get some data', inject([AsyncTestCompleter], (async) => {
  var connection;
  var injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
    MockBackend,
    provide(Http, {useFactory: (backend, defaultOptions) => {
      return new Http(backend, defaultOptions)
    }, deps: [MockBackend, DefaultOptions]})]);
  var http = injector.get(Http);
  var backend = injector.get(MockBackend);
  //Assign any newly-created connection to local variable
  backend.connections.subscribe(c => connection = c);
  http.request('data.json').subscribe((res) => {
    expect(res.text()).toBe('awesome');
    async.done();
  });
  connection.mockRespond(new Response('awesome'));
}));
```

If you want to use the `MockBackend` for the whole application use

```ts
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS, 
    provide(XHRBackend, {useClass: MockBackend}),
    provide(JSONPBackend, {useClass: MockBackend})]);
```

Ensure that the `MockBackend` providers come after `HTTP_PROVIDERS`.

If you want `MockBackend` to be use by specific components only, add

```ts
provide(XHRBackend, {useClass: MockBackend}),
provide(JSONPBackend, {useClass: MockBackend})
```

to the providers list of the component instead.

Comment: Thanks you, but how could i inject this so that whenever a component request a http object it gets my mock instead ?

Comment: If you want to do this for the whole application `bootstrap(AppComponent, [ HTTP_PROVIDERS, provide(XHRBackend, {useClass: MockBackend}),
provide(JSONPBackend, {useClass: MockBackend})]);`. Ensure that the `MockBackend` providers come after `HTTP_PROVIDERS`. if you want `MockBackend` only for specific components, add `, provide(XHRBackend, {useClass: MockBackend}),
provide(JSONPBackend, {useClass: MockBackend})` to the providers of the component instead.

Comment: Thank you, your comment helped find the solution, the one modification i did though was rather than passing {useClass : MockBackend} as provider is passed {useValue: backend} which contains the actual mocked backend ;).

Comment: Ah, sorry, the comment doesn't align with the code in my answer. Glad you figured it out :)